# wget url for finding a specific java version

Tags: java, wget

any WGET urls for downloading jdk1.8.0_121?
one of the product i use needs this exact version.
most of the urls got outdated..all the urls i have been using no longer works.
is there a standard way to find out the urls?

Comment: You can get it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html

Comment: nope...its very hard to get the url with wget

Comment: That's on purpose because you need to accept the license agreement first.